# AWS Lambda Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

A brief explanation of my setup.

1. I have an AWS S3 bucket with access set to `Not Public` which is called `myBucket`
2. I have a CloudFront distribution over the `myBucket`
3. I have created a lambda function (serverless image handler)

The desired behaviour is that my images are only accessible through my CloudFront distribution (and not directly using the S3 URL), and that I should be able to call my lambda function through the CloudFront URL.

Now what happens is that I am able to get my image like this:

```
https://d32by75bmg47jh.cloudfront.net/portrait.jpeg
```

But, I am **not able** to get the image by calling lambda:

```
https://d32by75bmg47jh.cloudfront.net/fit-in/500x500/portrait.jpeg
```

I am getting the **Access Denied** error when I try to call it with lambda.

My Bucket Policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E2FGH21TNURTU9"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
        }
}
```

In my `Lambda Console` have set my Lambda function to use the **Execution role: lambda_basic_execution**. In the `IAM Console` it's policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why am I still getting the Access Denied when I try to access my image through lambda?

Comment: An AccessDenied is most common when Cloudfront is trying to serve `fit-in/500x500/portrait.jpeg` from your bucket, but that file does not exist. What you haven't shown, but is probably the source of the error, is how you've configured the lambda@edge within cloudfront. If you share that I should be able to help a bit more.

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace It's not deployed to lambda@edge. It used to work actually before I started restricting the permissions, but now it doesn't anymore and I can't find why. But it was never using lambda@edge, even while it was still working. However, I tried to add lambda@edge now and got this:
"Environment variables are not supported.
Runtime must be one of: Node.js 6.10, Node.js 8.10.
Your function's execution role must be assumable by the edgelambda.amazonaws.com service principal."

Comment: OK- so all you did was restrict the permissions? If you check  the lambda's log is it invoking? Because my money is still very much on the lambda not being invoked at all...

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace Yeah, it's not invoking... the real question is why not

Comment: Indeed. Which is why I want to understand how your lambda was triggered when it was working?

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace I was just following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/template.html. And it was working as simply as invoking the URL with the /fit-in/.../ argument built in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182640/discussion-between-thomasmichaelwallace-and-wesleyy).

Comment: This is literally the only search result on Google for "Your function's execution role must be assumable by the edgelambda.amazonaws.com service principal." Seriously AWS, can you improve your developer experience?